# Supporting numbers with preceeding zeros in General formattted cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a requirement that a excel cell should support formula and also numbers with preceding 0s (like 000110). 
The solutions I tried like setting the cell type to Text, or adding apostrophe (') in front of cell value resulted in the loss of formulas support.

Please help me if there is any way where the above requirement can be satisfied.

Additional information:
The excel is being generated by our application which uses POI interface to read and write the excel sheets.

Comment: If you want variable leading zeroes, i.e. for data to be displayed as entered then, yes, you need text formatting - that can make some formulas behave differently (text and numbers that look the same are not the same for VLOOKUP, for example) but that's not insurmountable - are there specific formulas which cause problems?

Comment: Once we change the formatting to text, none of the formulas were evaluated by excel. they were simply treated as a normal text.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean - yes formula cells should not be text formatted - somehow you need the data cells to be text but the formulas not ....the values delivered by the formulas will be determined by a combination of the formula itself and/or the data referenced, depending on the formulas

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom format. To always display six digits, the custom format string would be 000000. If you need decimal places be sure to add those.

Comment: The no. of 0s is not constant.. It can be 09, 009, 0000121, etc. The solution should be generic to support any no. of preceding 0s

Comment: You can use VBA to set the custom format by cell. Alternatively you could have separate display cells and data cells, with the display cells being text formatted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click on the `Cell` or on `whole column`
2. Click on `Format Cell`
3. Click on `Custom`
4. Enter 6 zero's `000000` and click Ok

Refer the snapshot

[image]

Comment: The no. of 0s is not constant.. It can be 09, 009, 0000121, etc. The solution should be generic to support any no. of preceding 0s.

Comment: @KumarV: can you tell for each number, how many zeros should be there?